# Load AngularJS Template within page, dynamically

Tags: dynamic, dom-manipulation, angularjs

I have a page containing 2 controllers: one which manages a list of so-called 'apps', and another that is to place the new Angular template into the innerHTML of its Div element.

```
<div ng-controller="appList"></div>
<div ng-controller="appPane"> Dynamic content should be loaded here! </div>
```

I have tried using the standard {{expression}} bindings, but they do not work with html, I have also tried the ng-bind-html-unsafe directive (Binding the innerhtml to that of the App request's return) but controllers are not executed within this new code.

The problem seems to be that by using a Binding, Angular is not re-parsing the contents of the html in question to use it as an angular app. Any ideas of how to get it to parse dynamic content?

Comment: Are the 'apps' distinct Angular apps (each have an `ng-app` declaration?) or just different controllers/views for the same app?  If there are just different controllers/view, I would use the appList as your navigation and setup `$routeProviders` (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider) to manage the different views.

Comment: Probably a better solution than the one I was attempting, but I am still new to Angular, so I'll try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [uiRouter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) module (from the [AngularUI](http://angular-ui.github.io/) project). It adds the concept of states, which are pretty similar to routes, but with other goodies, such as the ability to nest them. For example:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('myState', {
        url: '/mystate',
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: 'MyCtrl'
    })
    .state('myState.substate', {
        url: '/{substate}',
        templateUrl: '...',
        controller: 'MySubCtrl'
    });
```

`MySubCtrl` will be activated whenever you go to `/mystate/something` and you can use that "something" as a parameter (see [`$stateParams`](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#wiki-stateparams-1)). You can nest states to any amount of levels.

Comment: That sounds really useful! Being that my answer was from the early development of Angular, this hadn't existed- Others feel free to comment if this should not be the case, but I feel this is now the correct answer. Accepted.

Comment: I'm happy that these things (the AngularJS ecosystem) are evolving the way they are.

Comment: For the record, I have tried this solution out in my own projects and it is extremely useful. There are a few issues, such as navigation to nonexistent routes resulting in errors, but I am betting that hidden in their moderate-depth documentation is a means of detecting when a route doesn't exist such that it could be handled. As a general-case scenario, I recommend this solution to anyone attempting to use routes, and I recommend skipping the official Route provider from Angular, as this one is so much more powerful.

Answer (score 27):

It appears that the $compile service, when fed the elements you wish to recompile along with your current scope, does what I was looking for.

Example from my source:

```
var appPane = $('#AppPane');//JQuery request for the app pane element.
appPane.html(data);//The dynamically loaded data
$compile(appPane.contents())($scope);//Tells Angular to recompile the contents of the app pane.
```

This should help anyone experiencing my problem, I hope.

Comment: If you don't have JQuery explicitly loaded, you can just `var appPane = document.getElementById` and `appPane.innerHTML = data)` and `$compile(containerElement)($scope)`

Answer (score 6):

Look at [$routes](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$route) and ngView in angularjs.

Here's a very basic example:

http://jsfiddle.net/pXpja/3/

Comment: This is the 'official' alternative, but does not currently work in situations requiring a layered structure of controllers as in my original problem.