# Angular loadview function

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a loadview function in Angular?  I googled, but got not much information. The method is to load external content. What is this function, and how to use that? Is there any documentation?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve ? Please share the link you are referring

Comment: Refer [Load AngularJS Template within page, dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318337/load-angularjs-template-within-page-dynamically)